# How do I find the code behind a JSP taglib?

Tags: jsp, taglib

I'm working on Tomcat5 (and migrating to tomcat6). We use JSP taglibs because that's how the site was delivered to us. The vendor build their tags, which has been very useful, but I've operated them like a black box. I know what goes in, I know what goes out, I know what one line to put in the header of each JSP page.

If you have tag, like `<irv:>` as in

```
<irv:validate name="status" datatype="API.STAT" datasource="local">*
```

and you know the tag line looks like this

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/inv.tld" prefix="irv" %>
```

How do you find the Java code behind it all?

All help appreciated.

Comment: Please do not confuse 3rd party taglibs with JSTL. JSTL is a JSP standard taglib: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info. I've edited the question to replace "JSTL" by "a JSP taglib".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the `/WEB-INF/tlds/inv.tld` file in a text editor. It contains tag definitions and for the `<irv:validate>` it'll contain something like

```
<tag>
    <name>validate</name>
    <tag-class>com.example.ValidateTag</tag-class>
    ...
</tag>
```

The `<tag-class>` gives you the full qualified classname of the backing Java code of the tag.

#### See also:

- [Java EE 5 tutorial - programming simple JSP tags](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnann.html)

Comment: BalusC, I knew the com.example... part. The link you included has the part I **really** didn't follow. This line tells me what I needed: *Tag handlers can be made available to a web application in two basic ways. The classes implementing the tag handlers can be stored in an unpacked form in the /WEB-INF/classes/ subdirectory of the web application. Alternatively, if the library is distributed as a JAR, it is stored in the /WEB-INF/lib/ directory of the web application.*<br/> Much thanks

Comment: So you aren't using an IDE where you can just search for the `com.example.ValidateTag` source file? E.g. Ctrl+Shift+T or Ctrl+Click classname in Eclipse. Anyway, as to your confusion, in first case it's present in `/WEB-INF/classes/com/example/ValidateTag.class`. In the second case, the class is present in some JAR file in `/WEB-INF/lib`. It just tells you the location of the `.class` file of the `com.example.ValidateTag`. But you should rather be interested in the `.java` file, otherwise you need to decompile the `.class` file yourself.

Comment: No, I only use Eclipse when doing Android development, and only because the time cost of not using it is too high in that case. I never warmed up to Eclipse even though the world seems to love it. I never find that a tool is where I expect it and I just can't tilt my head in a way that it all lines up and makes sense. I might ask my company to buy jBuilder as I do find the CodeGear IDEs easier.<br/>So how do I find the .java file?

Comment: Haha, the time shall come :) Anyway, did you find the file? Didn't the webapp ship with source code? That would seem strange to me, how would you ever maintain the code.

Comment: We have a good relationship with the vendor but he is too good at protecting his developers from his customers, so I speak to very nice people who are often more knowledgeable than me, but not as knowledgeable as I need. So, it is here, I just lack the tracking skills. So, how do I find the .java files?

Comment: The package is the folder structure. The classname is the file name. So, you need to use your OS-specific file system search engine (e.g. F3 in Windows Explorer) to search for a file called `ValidateTag.java` in some `com/example/`. If there isn't then try `ValidateTag.class` instead but it should be already present in webapp as `/WEB-INF/classes/com/example/ValidateTag.class` or in a JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib`. You only have to decompile it to get the real Java code. [JD](http://java.decompiler.free.fr) is useful.